# Who should our pro-tempore moderators be?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators

From [The 7 Essential Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/):

> Discussing the criteria of a great moderator is important and picking out potential candidates is a great way to introduce outstanding contributors to your community.

and from the [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) blog page:

> If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start one now! Pro Tem appointments will begin about two weeks after the site is created. The more guidance we receive, the more informed our choice.

- **Each nomination should be a separate answer**. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.

  - The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
  - Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

We're looking for members of this site who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

It's also good if the moderators:

- Are members with participation in both the meta and main site.
- Participated in Area 51, generate social network referrals, or blog about the site.
- Are members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

---

That's the general question used across Stack Exchange. I'll address some of the specific questions that have come up here:

- There are typically three pro-tem mods on a site - in fact, almost all sites, graduated or beta, across Stack Exchange, have at least three mods.
- Pro-tem mods serve until the next site election, which is typically after graduation. A mod can resign at any time if an issue crops up that makes it difficult for him or her to moderate.
- A person can nominate as many candidates as they want.

---

[The moderators have been chosen. . .](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194/moderator-pro-tem-announcement?cb=1)

Comment: By the way, Robert Cartaino - if you're around - do you think this should have the "featured" tag? Might get the question some more visibility and more nominations.

Comment: How many moderators are required & is there a limit on how many people an individual can nominate?

Comment: @Fred There's no nomination limit. Typically, a beta has three pro-tem mods.

Comment: As a side note: Those nominees without full editing privileges (yet) can post an acceptance/decline in a comment below the post, which can then be edited in.

Comment: Now that moderators have been chosen, should this question now be closed & the question title altered to include the date. When the question of moderators comes up again a new question can be raised, but it shouldn't be confused with this question.

Comment: @Fred I made the title edits. What close reason should be used here?

Comment: I just had a look at the options for closing & there isn't one that would apply in this case. I think including the completed notification & date, as you've done, are the main thing

Answer (score 15):

I'd like to put myself forward as a possible moderator pro tem.

Although I might not be the most evangelical moderator in terms of promoting the site externally, I have been an elected moderator on EE.SE for about a year now, and have a good deal of experience with the nature of the material on an engineering site and the kinds of users who hang out on such a site.

I moderate with a light hand, and can help take care of some of the administrative details as we take the site through its beta phase.

Comment: Impressive Resume and EE. SE credential +1 Vote

Comment: +1 vouch, I've been involved with EE.SE for a couple of years and he's a decent moderator.

Answer (score 13):

I nominate [GlenH7](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/16/glenh7)

He seems like a nice chap. Oh, yeah and he's clever and good at moderating and stuff too - I suppose that should come into it somewhere :P

---

*Edit from GlenH7*:

Thank you, and I accept the nomination.  I'd be happy to serve as a pro-tem moderator for the site.

Up until Engineering went into Beta, my primary SE site had been Programmers.  I'm one of the active community members there that work to keep the site tidy and the quality guidelines followed.  On Progs, I have approximately 2500 helpful flags; about 500 edits; and a ridiculous number of review items completed.  I'm also very familiar with the 10k tools and look forward to seeing what the mod tools offer in addition.  My work and background involve engineering, and I'm looking forward to being part of the site as it grows.

I believe each SE site forms its own community with their own rules.  My goal as a moderator would be to enforce the norms that we as an engineering community decide upon.  I agree with the [Theory of Moderation blogpost](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), which really means that site moderators are more like janitors - there to clean up the things the community can't take care of.  My hope is that we develop enough active users to provide strong community moderation, and I'll do my part to help grow that within our community.

Comment: +1 vote to you :-)

Answer (score 4):

I nominate [@jhabbott](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/95/jhabbott)

@jhabbott has been very active on this site. I believe he will make a good moderator. @jhabbott do you accept this challenge. :-)

---

Ok, I accept, but with the following caveats:

- I am not an experienced SE moderator but I am happy to learn.
- I can't commit any minimum amount of time, but would give whatever I can.
- I don't know how many mods will be needed to share the load adequately, but if there are enough better-qualified people to do this, I'll step aside in favour of them. Unless the other mods prefer the extra help and don't mind helping me learn about SE moderation in the process.

Answer (score 3):

Dear Nick I don't know either you or Tom.  But I'm going to upvote Tom and nominate you.

Seems like if you say, "I want someone better than this", then maybe you should run..?

Your [profile](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/63/nick-alexeev) looks nice.  I love sensors!

Comment: I accept this nomination.  I hope, that my experience from EE.SE will be put to a good use.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to nominate [HDE 226868](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/106/hde-226868)

HDE 226868 had a good reputation on SE, is already a moderator on another SE site & is associated with a number of scientific & technology sites on SE.

---

*Edit from HDE 226868*

**Nomination regretfully declined.**

I'm grateful for the nomination, but unfortunately I would not have the time required to carry out my duties as a moderator. For those who don't know, I'm a high school student, and given that I'm typically very busy with extracurricular activities, my time is limited. I have the time to moderate HSM, but that takes quite some time. I also find that it's hard for me to contribute a lot to multiple sites at the same time, though that doesn't seem to apply to community moderation tasks.

But don't be alarmed! I'll continue to contributing (and doing review tasks, so long as I have enough rep) on Engineering. You can always talk to me on chat, and I'll be active on meta. I'm busy for at least three-quarters of the day, but when I have enough time, I can contribute to Stack Exchange and help improve it to the best of my ability.

I'd also like to take this opportunity to give a nod to the other candidates. I like the nominations so far, and I can honestly say that there are others I'd vote for ahead of myself. I have a good feeling that site will be in the hands of some pretty good pro-tem mods. . .

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to nominate [Tom Au](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/62/tom-au).

Tom has lots of experience on a wide range of SE sites; he's a real veteran. Even a quick glance at his network profile will give you an idea of what he's like.

Tom also has one important quality: He's been active on Engineering throughout the private beta, and his questions and answers have covered a whole bunch of topics. He may not be proficient in all of them, but he has a very good overall knowledge of engineering - despite not necessarily being an engineer! (?)

**Edit from Tom Au**

**Decline for now.**

First, I greatly appreciate the nomination. I believe that my combination of an "engineering" and liberal arts background could bring "balance" to the site.

My main issue for now is "day job" pressures. My (small) tech company is in the process of negotiating a major hurdle. A successful negotiation of this hurdle would possibly free up more time for me on the site in six months to a year. Perhaps over that time frame, a then moderator will want to "rotate" and leave. If both these conditions converge, I would be happy to be considered as a back up or replacement moderator.

Comment: I have to disagree with this nomination.  No offense.  Tom has experience across many stacks, but most of them are humanitarian and entertainment.  IMO, the only stacks that can provide the right kind of experience are Programmers.SE and EE.SE .

Comment: +1 Vote for Tom Au. Tom Au has exhibited that he is a seasoned professional. The following response to me is the best response on engineering SE. http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119/in-engineering-fields-how-often-do-you-find-yourself-being-asked-to-be-a-sales/125#125. This type response only comes with a wealth of professional experience. More of Tom Au type professional will only enhance the site.

Answer (score 1):

I nominate [Trevor Archibald](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41/trevor-archibald). I think his contributions are well thought out and he is very active.